# accessing html elements with jquery using different ids or find method

Tags: php, jquery

i create my website with full of ajax works with php,jquery,mysql . When i do some action on element1 and many other html elements have to be accessed to get some values to send to server and also to display the results .

For this initially i was creating lengthy but unique ids for the html elements and used to create every required in jquery with string concatenation and then use them . But the code gets too lengthy

Then i saw that '.find' method helps to access the element without conflicts . here the code is reduced a lot

which one should i go for ?

Comment: **Quote:** _"...initially i was creating lengthy but unique ids..."_.  You are **supposed** to create "unique" id's for each element.  If you duplicate an id, the browser will likely ignore the duplicates and script behavior will be unpredictable across browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does the same job, I'd go for the simplest one. Then, there is less breaking points. Consider that less-Lengthy doesn't mean simpler. A step-by-step and well comented code is of course bigger, but much easier to understand.

Comment: when i try to access a html element with its id and if by chance copy of the same element with same id also appears on the screen , it will be a problem isnt it ?

Comment: Id by definition should be uniq. If you have duplicated ID, there is not an expected behaviour, you're playing outside the rules